# Not able to set SCNView's background color with colorWithPatternImage:

Tags: scenekit, uicolor

Why am I not able to set the SCNView's backgroundColor property to a color pattern?

```
    // configure the view's background color
    scnView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];   // this works

    // doesn't seem to work with SCNView 
    scnView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"]];

    // tried this in a different example with just a UIView and it works   
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"]];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is an excerpt from the documentation.  [colorWithPatternImage:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicolor/1621935-colorwithpatternimage)

> You can use pattern colors to set the fill or stroke color just as you
>   would a solid color. During drawing, the image in the pattern color is
>   tiled as necessary to cover the given area.

Comment: I like SceneKit, but there always seems to be a few 'gotchas'. In this case it's documented in the fine print. From [`SCNView.backgroundColor`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnview/1523088-backgroundcolor), "This property’s value must be a color that can be represented using RGBA components.", a pattern image is more than just RGB so I'd take that to mean it's unsupported.

Comment: As a workaround you could look at placing the SCNView over the top of an UIView with your pattern image. I've not tried this however. Another approach would be to place a large plane in the back of your SceneKit scene and apply the image to it as a tiled texture. This will work, but you'll likely have to attach the plane's node to the camera node to ensure it stays in place.

Comment: Placing a UIView behind the SCNView is a great idea and it works.  Thanks.

Comment: If you write this up as an answer - I can mark/tag it as an accepted one.